# Using regex in MongoDB then/else

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to search for a close match, I have the following mongoose query

```
 $cond: {
  if: { $eq: ["$postType", "sports"] }
  then: {
   $eq: ["$title", "El classic"]
  }
  else: {}
 }
```

I will be filtering with **title**, so at the then block I want to be able to use regex to search for a match with whatever is provided, how can I achieve this please?

Comment: Check [MongoDB Docs: $eq](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/). You can pass object with regex instead of string condition.

Comment: thanks, but I still can't filter correctly, after passing an object with regex
`$eq: ["$title", {$regex: "El classic"}]`

Comment: There is no "close match" feature in mongodbs query logic. You will have to write explicitly how to match your search. Doing this efficiently can actually become quite complex. Maybe search for implementations by larger companies, e.g. netflixes blog. - the closest thing you can try is to match 'toLower' or 'subStr'.